# Modelling 3-level MLM of longitudinal data in R

Tags: r, regression, panel-data, multilevel-analysis

I have two questions regarding modeling a 3-level multilevel model in R.

I have a dataset of different variables that were assessed 4x as part of a longitudinal study. At each of the four assessments that were 1 month apart, participants filled out questionnaires (= one mean score per participant per assessment) and used daily diary/ecological momentary assessment (EMA) over the course of 4 days. My issue is that the EMA data consists of individual entries per day per assessment (e.g., 3 entries on 4 days = 12 total entries per assessment). This data is on a different level than the questionnaire data (clustered within a person in addition to the timepoint level).

I am unsure how to calculate a model where I can include the EMA data as a predictor of the questionnaire data while acknowledging the individual entries.

So far, I have used a two-level model where I aggregated the EMA data to yield a mean per timepoint so it matches the data from the questionnaire. So level 1 is the within-person variation across the three timepoints, and level 2 is the between-person variation.

However, because I aggregated the EMA data, I lost the advantages of the dense data that was collected. I don't know how to perform a 3-level MLM where I include the individual EMA entries per day nested in each assessment.

As it is now, my data is in long format (and in addition to the original long format, I have also centered it around the grand mean and within clusters (=individual person), but that is not included here in this sample data). I hope I described the data type sufficiently.

```r
structure(list(id = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 
                                1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
                                3, 3), label = "serial", 
    format.spss = "N12", display_width = 12L), 
               time = structure(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2),   
    format.spss = "F4.0"), 
               gender = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2), 
    label = "gender", format.spss = "F3.0", display_width = 5L, 
    labels = c(`na` = -9, female = 1, male = 2, other = 3), 
    class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")),
    questionnaire_mean = structure(c(9, 7, NA, NA, 6, 6, 13, 8, 11, 
        7), 
    format.spss = "F8.2", display_width = 10L), 
               ema_mean = structure(c(4.21, 5, NA, 5, 2.6, 
                                      NA, NA, 5.9, 2.95, 2.79), 
    format.spss = "F8.2", display_width = 10L)), 
    row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```